# Handling RuntimeExceptions in certain circumstances valid?

Tags: java, exception, user-input

As I understand it from several tutorials, RuntimeExceptions are actually not supposed to be caught, because they shall reveal inappropiate usage of methods, especially APIs, correct?
Furthermore, one might assume that the program is not able to recover from RuntimeExceptions.
Now, I experienced a case where I might receive an IndexOutOfBoundsException due to invalid user input: the program receives a String from a HTML-form and wants to validate it if it contains an integer.
Basically the assigned String is matched with a pattern and then the comma's position is determined. Afterwards, it's necessary to examine the first digit behind the comma to decide how to round it correctly. That's the critical part:

```
        firstDecimalChar = formattedValue.charAt(dotPosition + 1);
```

This statement throws the Exception if the user entered something like "27." Due to the fact that this is based on weird user input, I wondered if this Exception actually behaves like a common exception (so to say).
The reason I think this is that in most tutorials (e.g. [oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catchOrDeclare.html)) they categorize *checked* Exceptions as errors which result from invalid input, i.e. wrong path name to a file that shall be opened, and with some correction or a user hint it's possible to recover from that error. Same here: one might simply set above variable to zero, because that's what it means when somebody inserts "27." -> "27.0"

Is that catch and specify requirement really that strict? Of course, one can simple check beforehand if the position isn't out of bounds, but my question is if there is really such a straight line between *checked* and *unchecked* exceptions. I'm wondering if there are any technical disadvantages why exceptions should be avoided as often as possible. (Somebody mentioned JVM-overhead, but is it that significant?)

I think I need some more in-depth clarification here, because most tutorials don't convince me with: "you simply shouldn't do that". Because I think in this case, this exception behaves like a *checked* Exception from which it is easy to recover from.

**Note:** In my code I check if the string position is valid or not beforehand and don't catch the exception - so that's not part of this question : ) But this case keeps me busy, still.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is that catch and specify requirement really that strict?

No, I think its ok to catch unchecked exceptions (`RuntimeExceptions`) in certain situations.

For example, if a user enters a number, I think it's perfectly fine to do

```
double i;
try {
    i = Double.parseDouble(userInput);
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    addValidationError("Entered number is not valid: " + userInput);
}
```

If an exception is *unexpected* and corresponds to an error in the code, don't bother catching it (or catch in at the top most level, such as in `handleRequest` or whatever, and return a 500 error for example). On the other hand, if you can foresee an exception being thrown, (and it's problematic to use ordinary control structures such as `if` statements to cover those cases, such as in the `NumberFormatException` example above) catch it and handle it.

As it happens, RuntimeExceptions often correspond to programmer errors, and saying *"don't catch RuntimeExceptions"* can probably be seen as a good approximation of what to catch and not to catch.

When a developer decides whether to extend `Exception` or `RuntimeException` he/she will think about whether it's reasonable to *force* the clients to declare throws clauses / catch the exception. In some cases an exception can be a due to both a programming error and a "normal operation" error. In such cases it's kind of impolite to force `throws`/`catch` upon the clients, and it's more suitable to make it a `RuntimeException`. In client code, where the exception is in fact used to indicate "normal operation" error, it is still appropriate to catch it.

Related question (but closed as primarily opinion-based): stackoverflow.com/questions/24344511/why-is-catching-a-runtimeexception-not-considered-a-good-programming-practice

Comment: I really dislike that Java doesn't have a way to check if a string is an integer without throwing an exception. String validation is not an exceptional case/problem. They should bring C#'s TryParse to Java.

Comment: @RoyT. A simple regex allows you to check if a `String` is an integer. (`"-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?"`

Comment: @ChetanKinger true, though it would be nice if all primitive types had a built in check. Instead we need to wrestle with regexes and stuff. In most cases that means programmers rather be lazy and just use a try catch :).

Comment: @RoyT., I agree. `tryParse` would be a useful addition to the API. Perhaps it's not included because it takes like 4 lines to write it yourself.

Comment: @aioobe thanks, aioobe : ) it's good to know that _unchecked_ exceptions are kind of ambivalent, that fact was never stated precisely in my sources. Do you know if there is a disadvantage when exceptions are thrown (larger overhead, e.g.) and if it's worth taking this into consideration?

Answer (score 2):

> As I understand it from several tutorials, RuntimeExceptions are
>   actually not supposed to be caught, because they shall reveal
>   inappropiate usage of methods, especially APIs, correct?

Not really. You can always catch a `RuntimeException` and wrap it in a checked `Exception` and `throw` it back to the caller for them to decide whether to kill the app or wrap up the error in a format that can be understood by the user

Example :

```
try {
    //read parameters
    String processType = args[9]; 
    String username = args[11];
    //read more parameters..
} catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
   throw new InvalidInputException("Wrong number of input parameters passed. See usage notes"+e);
}
```

Comment: this answer does help me, after all :D This is in fact a good solution for staying conform with [Oracle's Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catchOrDeclare.html) that _checked_ Exceptions are ment to indicate problems with user input. It resolves the ambivalence of a RuntimeException when it is triggered due to inappropriate IO because it converts it

Answer (score 1):

I think a Runtime exception signifies something that should really never happen during the execution of a program. For example an IOException is not a runtime exception: an IOException happens because something outside the control of the program (the filesystem in this case) is misbehaving.

However, an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException happens while the program is in complete control. So it is a RuntimeException. It signifies that the programmer did something wrong. For example a wrong calculation of an array index.

Let's image a program that does not interact with the outside world at all (no IO, etc..) this program should never throw an Exception because it is in complete control of everything that happens. If it does throw an Exception it means the programmer did something wrong (or was very lazy).

*Note: I completely rewrote this answer because I first didn't see the note at the end of the question :)*

Comment: I agree, that a program without IO shouldn't throw exceptions because it knows what values are to be expected from methods : ) But my case assumes, that IO is necessary and it _is_ actually the reason why suddenly an Exception becomes a possible output, at all. The user might insert something that I would never output with methods, e.g. "27." Because this is neither a floating-point nor an integer, that I might have converted to a String ^^ That was what lead me to the conclusion, that a RuntimeException suddenly needs to be treated like a _checked_ one, because of it's dependency on the user

Comment: I think that an ArrarayIndexOutOfBoundsException is not due to bad user input, but due to a lazy programmer not checking user input. And so i should be a runtime exception and should not be caught. Instead you should fix the code (by adding checks) :). The reason harddisk IO is a CheckedException is that you , for example, cannot control if someone deletes a file while you are reading it.  However, you have full control over variables that were obtained using IO.

Answer (score 1):

Some runtime or third party methods (like `Integer.parseInt`) report the validation error through exception. If we need this validation functionality, we need to catch the exception.

It would probably be better to have something like `Integer.isValid(String x)` but abundant homegrown replacements of standard libraries are also problematic.

Comment: so you think, actually, this problem can be seen as an inadequate implementation, do you? That's interesting, tbh. Many people stated that other languages are capable of such validations. So maybe it's true that programmers using _unchecked_ Exceptions are indeed a little lazy, even if they're working at Oracle's, 'cause it seems as if they would've been able to come up with something better ^^